# Faster way to rank rows in subgroups in pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas

I have a pandas data frame that has is composed of different subgroups.

```
df = pd.DataFrame({
'id':[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8], 
'group':['a', 'a', 'a', 'a', 'b', 'b', 'b', 'b'], 
'value':[.01, .4, .2, .3, .11, .21, .4, .01]
})
```

I want to find the rank of each id in its group with say, lower values being better.  In the example above, in group A, Id 1 would have a rank of 1, Id 2 would have a rank of 4.  In group B, Id 5 would have a rank of 2, Id 8 would have a rank of 1 and so on.

Right now I assess the ranks by:

1. Sorting by value.

```
df.sort('value', ascending = True, inplace=True)
```

2. Create a ranker function (it assumes variables already sorted)

```
def ranker(df):
    df['rank'] = np.arange(len(df)) + 1
    return df
```

3. Apply the ranker function on each group separately:

```
df = df.groupby(['group']).apply(ranker)
```

This process works but it is really slow when I run it on millions of rows of data.  Does anyone have any ideas on how to make a faster ranker function.

Answer (score 52, accepted):

rank is cythonized so should be very fast. And you can pass the same options as `df.rank()`
[here](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.rank.html?highlight=rank#pandas.DataFrame.rank) are the docs for `rank`. As you can see, tie-breaks can be done in one of five different ways via the `method` argument.

Its also possible you simply want the `.cumcount()` of the group.

```
In [12]: df.groupby('group')['value'].rank(ascending=False)
Out[12]: 
0    4
1    1
2    3
3    2
4    3
5    2
6    1
7    4
dtype: float64
```

Comment: of course! there is a function for it!  That said, it doesn't quite do the same thing as my function above because if there is a tie in values, my function will randomly give one id a higher rank than another id with the same value.  Although .rank()'s way of handling same values is rather sensible, for my purposes, I need the output produced by my function.  Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 15):

Working with a big DataFrame (13 million lines), the method rank with groupby maxed out my 8GB of RAM an it took a really long time. I found a workaround less greedy in memory , that I put here just in case:

```
df.sort_values('value')
tmp = df.groupby('group').size()
rank = tmp.map(range)
rank =[item for sublist in rank for item in sublist]
df['rank'] = rank
```